# Is it permissible for me to uncover my hair in front of female cousins who are atheists?

Tags: non-muslim, hijab

My question is regarding the hijab of a woman. Is it permissible for me to uncover my hair in front of female cousins (mothers sisters daughters) who are atheists?

Is it permissible for me to uncover my hijab in front of sisters, mother, grandmother, cousins, aunts who are Muslim but not fully practicing Muslims (for example, who don't read all of their salah on time)?

Answer (score 0):

If they are female, you may uncover. If they are male, no. This is a general rule, but your own discretion should also play a role. Also if the male non-Muslim relatives are father or brother, it is permitted to remove the hijab when with them unless they have a history of inappropriate behavior.

Comment: An evidence to support your claim would be helpful!

Comment: What if the females are homosexual? and they feast on her beauty in a way a non mahram man wouldn't even dare to do?

Comment: @QaisarKhan The question only asks about female relatives who are atheists. Religion per se is not mentioned as a condition of hijab; rather, gender and family relations are specified. If these are cousins and she knows they are atheists, she probably knows if they are lesbians too. And if so, proper behavior is left up to the supposedly functioning mind of the Muslima in question. Not all homosexuals are rampant aggressors, and not all lesbians act out their desires. Just like if one knows a relative to be a thief, you don't leave your purse out to be stolen. The same with hijab.